# How do I "include" defines in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I'm a C++ programmer who is just starting to program Windows apps in C# using .NET.

I'm looking at some example code at MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx) and I see the following (partial) code:

```
const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
//This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.
const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

// Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, Console.ReadLine(),
    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);
```

So the variables `LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT` and `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` are defined in the example code explicitly. In contrast, if I was writing this in C++ I could have just included Winbase.h which has already defined these variables:

```
#define LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE       2
#define LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK           3
#define LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH             4
#define LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE           5
#define LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK            7
```

Is there a way to do the same type of thing in C#? So, is there some magic that makes me able to use `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` without defining it myself in the C# code? I dont mean by reusing the header, but how it is done in General in c#. It seems pretty error prone to me if I have to copy paste these values manually. Above that it would not fully appreciate the hard work that the person typing in these defines had done!

Comment: Usually, when interacting with the windows libraries, someone's done most of the work already over at http://www.pinvoke.net (a wiki specifically for the purpose of documenting interacting with win32/other unmanaged apis). For instance: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser (see "C# User-Defined Types" on this page)

Comment: It's not clear from the question if you mean reusing specific C\C++ header files from C#, or how it is done is general in C#.

Comment: I mean the later. How is this normally done in c#?

Comment: @spender So you mean, just copy/paste the enum from this website? Still feels pretty dirty...

Comment: @frank yes, it's dirty, but it seems to be the most comprehensive resource on the matter, so I can live with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same way C++ tries to make your code more, let's say, categorized than C code, having classes instead of functions (which, in the case of C, you would try to group, by convention, by using the same long prefix), C# forces yourself even more into categorizing your code to avoid even more the "global items" practice that you just described for your C++ equivalent.

Therefore, you want a constant in C#? Good, just put it in a class, and then use Class.MY_CONSTANT from other code that needs it.

In this particular case, though, seems that there are several constants referring to the same "domain", so smells like members of an enum to me. Learn C# enums, they are very useful and allow you to have more succint code than the C++ equivalent.

Comment: I feel compelled to note that C and C++ have enums, too. The Windows SDK headers are all *C* headers, and old ones at that. If they were written today, they would undoubtedly use scoped enums. This is not a unique advantage to C#. In fact, it is rather a limitation of C#, like Java, that *everything* is a class.

Comment: you're so wrong, not everything is a class in C#, we have primitive types, structs, etc

Comment: The primitive types are implemented as structs, and while structs are different from classes in a technical sense, they are not *conceptually* different. Perhaps I should have that last portion of my comment differently. Unlike C# (and Java), which are strictly object-oriented programming languages, C++ is a *multi-paradigm* programming language that offers OOP as only one of its many paradigms. It is nigh-impossible to implement a free function in C#.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't use directly the C++ headers in C#.

Moreover, I would prefer using an [`Enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) to store these kind of values.

What you **can** do if you're willing to put some time in learning these C# features is using [CodeDom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx)/[T4 Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to generate C# code from C++ headers. 
Which would reduce the hassle/error likeliness of a human copying the values over.

There might be some tools already available that provide these kind of features but since I didn't have to interact with too much unmanaged code, I did not *yet* search for one.